# Best way to add a green checkmark in Unicode

Tags: c#, wpf, unicode, mvvm-light

I'm working on a project in mvvm light.  I'd like to have a green check mark that comes from the PropertyCHanged in the view model.  I know I can do a regular black check mark with something like :

```
ProjectDbStatus = "\u221A" + "Project Database not found";
```

Is there a way to change this to a green check mark without changing the color of the text?

Comment: [U+221A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221A/index.htm) is the symbol for square-root, not a check mark. For a checkmark use U+2713, like @mybirthname suggests.

Comment: @CodesInChaos u221A produced a check  mark.  A black one at that.

Comment: @Crayams Depending on the font the symbol for square-root may look similar to a check mark, but it isn't a check mark. Use U+2713.

Comment: @CodesInChaos  ok but still doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @Crayams Unicode does not concern itself with color. (Only exception I know is that some renderers (which probably does not include WPF) render emoji in color)

Comment: Crayams, as @CodesInChaos pointed out there is no way to express colors in string. You probably wanted to ask different question like "how to render string with multiple colors in WPF" or something like that - as asked now there is no way to do it.

Comment: You could use two labels, one with green color containing a checkmark and one in black that contains the text. You might even use an image as checkmark.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: `You might even use an image as checkmark.` Why? The unicode char will scale well on higher DPI screens and a pixel-image not...

Comment: Well I was going to do image.  But I was hoping you could pass a hex color value in  to affect the unicode.

Comment: This was more of a curiosity question than hey how do I do this.  I've already got conditional code for calling different images.  Just looking at different ways to skin a cat.

Comment: Fishing around for different approaches doesn't seem like a good use of StackOverflow resources. That leads to overly broad questions. There are too many different ways to do this, from composing different elements, to `RichTextBox`. Without at least some constraint that would help us to understand what the best approach would be _in your scenario_, there's no good answer.

Comment: Lol.  So I posted a question with code and I'm fishing.  Isn't this a resource for developers?